# How to populate a mongoose schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following mongoose schemas

```
var postTable = mongoose.Schema({
userPost:{type : String},
dateCreated: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
_replies:[{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'reply_table'}],
_creator:{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}
});
```

and

```
var reply_table = mongoose.Schema({
userReply:{type:String},
date_created:{type:Date, default: Date.now},
_post:{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'post'},
_creator:{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}
});
var userPost = module.exports = mongoose.model("Post",postTable);

var userReply = module.exports = mongoose.model('reply_table',reply_table);
```

User can create post which will be entered into the Post table and other users can comment or reply to a post which will be entered into the reply_table.
I then try to populate the the post table like this

```
module.exports.getPost = function (callback) {
var mysort = { dateCreated: -1 };
userPost
    .find({},callback)
    .sort(mysort)
    .populate('_creator','username')
    .populate(' _replies')
    .exec(function (err,post) {
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log(post)
    });
  };
```

When the console prints out the post it prints the post information and a object with the user information becausei have another schema setup for users, therefore I used `.populate('_creator','username')`

The problem is it wont print the reply information it only prints an empty array: reply[].

I'm pretty sure I'm doing everything right. I used the following code to insert information into the reply_table

```
//make a reply on a post
module.exports.make_reply = function (user_id,pid,reply,callback) {
var newReply = userReply({
    _creator: user_id,
    _post: pid,
    userReply: reply
});
newReply.save(callback);
}
```

I know this question is very long but does anyone have any idea of what I might be doing wrong. I only want to populate the Post schema with information from the reply_table

Comment: Is there a blog post out there somewhere that shows this usage of `module.exports` for a mongoose model function? There seems to be a lot of questions of late where people are doing this. You actually want [instance methods](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#methods) for this.

Comment: I think module.exports would be simpler to implement

Comment: Well if it was then you wouldn't need to ask the question now would you? It would be best to accept you are doing it wrong and follow what the documentation says. That way you would already be moving on to more important things. Seems like sound advice to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out a solution to my question. What i did was i created a function to insert the reply id into the post table. It basically get the comment by its id and push a reply into the _replies array in the post table.

```
//Insert reply into post table
 module.exports.addReply = function (id,reply) {
 userPost.update({_id:id},{$push:{replies:reply}},{multi:true},function 
(err,post) {
});
}
```

When i use the getPost function it populates the reply table

```
module.exports.getPost = function (callback) {
var mysort = {dateCreated: -1};
userPost
    .find({}, callback)
    .sort(mysort)
    .populate('_creator', 'username')
    .populate('replies')
    .exec(function (err) {
        if(err) throw err;
    });
   };
```